# analysing data in excel using python

Tags: python, excel

This excel sheet represents the data of the houses. What I want to know how I can use the Python code so that it sorts the houses according to the number of rooms and knows the number of houses according to the rooms, for example, the houses that have two rooms =500 and so on after the houses are sorted by the number of rooms. I want to use a module that calculates the average price of houses according to The number of rooms only, in other words, it collects the total price of houses according to the number of rooms and divides it by their number to find the average price. For example, the number of houses with 4 rooms is 678. The average price is the total price of these houses divided by 678 is there any function I can use to do this?[excel sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYSJl.png)

Comment: You should investigate openpyxl

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.